# Printing matlab output into excel file - how to choose the correct starting row?

Tags: excel, matlab

I want to start my output in excel file A3:E3, but fail to implement this into my code.

```
for i=1:numel(item)       
    currentitem=struct2cell(item(i));   
    xlswrite('Output', currentitem',sprintf('A%d:E%d',i,i));

end
```

any help is appreciated!

Comment: What doesn't work? With your code, given that `i` loops from `1`  to `numel(item)`, you will be writing to `A1:E1`, `A2:E2`, `A3:A3`, etc... Also, shouldn't `'Output'` be `'Output.xls'` or `'Output.xlsx'`? You can use the syntax `[status,msg] = xlswrite(...)` which will give you the error message if it fails.

Comment: @am304 , the code starts writing in the excel file at A1:E1, but I want that the first two rows (i.e. A1:E1, A2:E2) are blank to fill it with other information and that this loop starts writing at A3:E3. Do you know how I can implement that?

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want to change where the loop starts writing (based on your comments), the only line you have to change is:

```
xlswrite('Output', currentitem',sprintf('A%d:E%d',i,i));
```

to

```
xlswrite('Output', currentitem',sprintf('A%d:E%d',i+2,i+2));
```

so that when `i=1`, it starts `A3:E3`.